# Highlight Partial Matches in a Single Column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can I highlight Partial matches in a single column of google sheets? some entries are the same but they have slight misspellings or some are in lowercase. How do you highlight these partial matches? thank you very much

[image: Im hoping it would like this]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=(INDEX(COUNTIF(REGEXREPLACE(A:A, "[^A-Za-z]+", ), 
                REGEXREPLACE(A1,  "[^A-Za-z]+", )))>1)*(A1<>"")
```

[image]

what this does is that regex will delete everything which is not `A-Z` or `a-z`

Comment: thank you so much! This is what I need!

Although another problem arose it will detect Zone1 and Zone2 as the same but I guess I'll have to live with that!

Thank you very much!!

Comment: @JaredBarile you can change `[^A-Za-z]+` to `[^A-Za-z0-9]+` to not remove numbers

Comment: may I ask what this code is for. It works great but it's bugging me because I dont understand how it works *(A1<>"")

Comment: @JaredBarile sure. means: "and A1 is not empty" and it assures that conditional formatting will not paint empty cells in the column